# Decrypt Password as string

Tags: database, mysql, password, super-admin

We are using ExpressionEngine **v2.10.1**, we are going to import data from the database. We have created API that returns data as JOSN by using:

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT * FROM exp_member_data"}
```

But we also need the used password as a string so we can encrypt it according to our own way. **Is there any way to get the password as a string?**

Comment: Its not possible to get the original password. It is saved in DB with hash algorithm using md5 or SHA...

Comment: @Mufi this sounds like the start of an answer...

Answer (score 0):

Password is highly confidential thing for website. It is important to save the password in any non decrypt algorithm so if someone attack on site and steal all the information, they cannot use the passwords.

ExpressionEngine do similar thing by encrypt password with md5 or SHA algorithm that is not possible to decrypt.

So, the answer of your question is: **It is not possible to get password as a String**